Empty LIBPATH in link command in cmake ninja build
I'm building a C++ project with cmake and using ninja as the generator.
The compilation breaks at linking the final executable because the linker is being passed an incorrect argument, namely: -LIBPATH:""
The ninja build file has the following rule:
build CMakeFiles\SeminarCG.dir\cmake_device_link.obj: CXX_EXECUTABLE_DEVICE_LINKER__SeminarCG_RelWithDebInfo CMakeFiles\SeminarCG.dir\src\main.obj CMakeFiles\SeminarCG.dir\src\testing_pipeline.obj CMakeFiles\SeminarCG.dir\src\util_cuda\edge_pt.obj | sdf.lib meshview.lib assimp-vc143-mt.lib SDFGen_lib.lib glfw3dll.lib zlibstatic.lib C$:\Program$ Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\libs\python310.lib || SDFGen_lib.lib assimp-vc143-mt.dll glfw3.dll meshview.lib sdf.lib zlibstatic.lib
  LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS = -D_WINDOWS -Xcompiler="/W3 /GR /EHsc" -Xcompiler="-MD -Zi -O2 -Ob1" -DNDEBUG
  LINK_LIBRARIES = sdf.lib meshview.lib SDFGen_lib.lib opengl32.lib zlibstatic.lib "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\libs\python310.lib" cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
  LINK_PATH = -LIBPATH:C:\Users\jnawocki\seminar\cg-seminar-2023\build  -LIBPATH:""  -LIBPATH:C:\PROGRA~1\NVIDIA~2\CUDA\v11.8\lib\x64
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles\SeminarCG.dir
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = CMakeFiles\SeminarCG.dir\
  TARGET_FILE = CMakeFiles\SeminarCG.dir\cmake_device_link.obj
  TARGET_IMPLIB = SeminarCG.lib
  TARGET_PDB = SeminarCG.pdb

As you can see the LIBPATH is empty which causes an error.
I managed to isolate the problem to one of my in-source dependencies: pybind11 by removing it from my executable's target_link_libraries() call. It is also built using a cmake project.
My question is: Which cmake commands/steps/etc. set the LIBPATH value and how can I further locate the problem in the pybind11 cmake files. Their cmake is pretty big and I've been trying to find the problem unsuccessfully for some time now with no success.

Which error do you get? How does CMakeLists.txt look like?

[build] LINK : fatal error LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/LIBPATH:'
The cmake code boils down to this:
add_subdirectory(extern/pybind11) ... add_executable(SeminarCG ${SOURCES}) target_link_libraries(SeminarCG PUBLIC pybind11::embed)
